# Using observables to make cancellable setTimeouts for sequential animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs

I have an array of objects that represent different animations depending on the *type* key of the object. I'm running the animations one after another with a constant delay between them using `setTimeout`.
I'm running the code below inside a function in a react component.

```js
animations.forEach((animation, index) => {
      switch (animation.type) {

        case "animation-type": {

          setTimeout(() => {
            //change the style of some elements
          }, index * 1000);

          break;
        }

        ...

        default:
          break;
      }
});
```

The whole process above is working properly as expected except that I can't stop it once it has begun. I want to be able to stop the process at some point for whatever reason and cancel the remaining animations waiting for their turn.

I'm looking for a simple way to do it declaratively, and the only option I can think of is by using observables from rxjs to make the process cancellable. However, I'm having a hard time adjusting the process above to use observables as I'm fairly new to rxjs.

Long story short, I want to make this process cancellable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zip` stream creation below sends one object to the subscribed lambda every 1000ms. It ends as soon as there are no more objects.

`takeUntil` is one of the more generic operators you can use to control when a stream ends. In this case, the moment `cancel$` emits a value, the entire stream ends.

```
const cancel$ = new Subject();
zip(
  from(animations), 
  interval(1000)
).pipe(
  takeUntil(cancel$),
  map(([x,y]) => x)
).subscribe(animation => {
  switch (animation.type) {
    case "animation-type": {
      //change the style of some elements
      ...
    default:
      break;
  }
});
```

Then, if you need this to stop, you can run this line

```
cancel$.next();
```

Of course, instead of subscribing with a lambda function, you can pass in an observer object.

```
).subscribe({
  next: animation => {
    switch (animation.type) {
      case "animation-type": {
        //change the style of some elements
        ...
      default:
        break;
    }
  },
  complete: () => {
    // Final touches/ reset the animation/ whatever
  },
  error: err => {
    console.log("Got an error: " + err.message);
    throw(err);
  }
})
```

Comment: neat, but why are you passing  the [x, y] array  to the map operator?

Comment: Zip can take a list of observables and outputs an array. In this case, the `x` is a value from your animations array and the `y` is a value from the interval. Since the interval only arrives every second, the tuple only arrived every second. However, we don't care about the values of the interval. So we take in the tuple `[x, y]` and return just `x`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the timeout functions:

```js
    const timeouts = [];

    animations.forEach((animation, index) => {
          switch (animation.type) {
    
            case "animation-type": {
    
              timeouts[index] = setTimeout(() => {
                //change the style of some elements
              }, index * 1000);
    
              break;
            }
    
            ...
    
            default:
              break;
          }
    });
```

then:

```
timeouts.map(timer=> clearTimeout(timer));
```

If you are working in a react project you can use [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook

```js
    const timeouts = useRef([]);


    animations.forEach((animation, index) => {
          switch (animation.type) {
    
            case "animation-type": {
    
              timeouts.current[index] = setTimeout(() => {
                //change the style of some elements
              }, index * 1000);
    
              break;
            }
    
            ...
    
            default:
              break;
          }
    });
```

And clear the timeout:

```
timeouts.current.map(timer=> clearTimeout(timer));
```